# Rails - Rubocop - Begin + Rescue syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubocop

I have the following code:

```
  def payload
    begin
      @payload ||= Warden::JWTAuth::TokenDecoder.new.call(token)
    rescue JWT::ExpiredSignature => e
      Rollbar.warning(e)
    end
  end
```

From brief reading of a few blogs I'm supposed to be using begin rescue and end to handle the error as I'm doing above, however I'm getting a redundant 'begin' rubocop warning.

Is begin only used when specifying a bit of code that may cause an error within a larger block? And is it therefore redundant here?

Thanks in advance

EDIT: And if I don't need it, is it written as

```
  def payload
    @payload ||= Warden::JWTAuth::TokenDecoder.new.call(token)
  rescue JWT::ExpiredSignature => e
    Rollbar.warning(e)
  end
```

?

Comment: `begin ... end` can also be used for non-`rescue` reasons - most notable of them is probably `begin ... end while test`. (or `until`), which guarantees one pass through the loop before `test` is checked.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Do this when the begin would be the first thing in your method

```
def payload
  @payload ||= Warden::JWTAuth::TokenDecoder.new.call(token)
rescue JWT::ExpiredSignature => e
  Rollbar.warning(e)
end
```

Comment: ...and the matching `end` would be the last :D

Answer (score 11):

Method bodies, block bodies, and lambda bodies are implicit exception blocks. You don't need to wrap the *entire code* of a method body, block body, or lambda body in a `begin` / `rescue` / `else` / `ensure` / `end` exception block, since it is already implicitly one. So, whenever you have something like

```
def foo
  begin
  rescue
  end
end
```

or

```
foo do
  begin
  rescue
  end
end
```

or

```
-> do
  begin
  rescue
  end
end
```

you can replace it with just

```
def foo
rescue
end
```

or the equivalent for blocks and lambdas.